# Passing parameter in TextBox using Ajax and MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want in the UI that the user enter a number inside a textbox and then show him in the same page using AJAX a record of all the artists with age less than the number the user entered.
My doubt is that I don't know how to pass the number entered into the textbox using Ajax to the PartialViewResult method inside my Controller Class

Controller class:

```
 public PartialViewResult GetByAgeLessThan(int age)
        {
            List<Artist> list = ope.ArtistLessThanAge(age);
            return PartialView("GetByAgeLessThan", list);
        }
```

This is my Artists index view(I want to show the results in it using Ajax). My big doubt is in here.. what should I do to pass the number entered inside the textbox to my PartialViewResult inside my controller??? There should be something wrong in this code... when I press the submit button nothing happens:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetByAgeLessThan", "Artists", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "divajax",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})){
    <h4>Search</h4>
    @Html.TextBox("txtAge")        
    <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Search"/>
    }
```

Comment: I would create a view model class, with the list and the age, that would be sent to the PartialViewResult. `return PartialView("GetByAgeLessThan", new MyPartialViewModel { Age = age, List = list})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When razor executes the line `@Html.TextBox("txtAge")`, It is going to render the below output

```
<input id="txtAge" name="txtAge" type="text" value="">
```

For model binding to work, you need to have your form field names same as your action method parameter name(s).

So change

```
@Html.TextBox("txtAge")
```

to

```
@Html.TextBox("age")
```

and it should work fine.

Or you can update your action method parameter name to `txtAge` ( *I don't like that parameter name :)* )

Comment: it works!! and 'age' parameter changed to 'txtAge' :)